# How to add a directory to an Amazon-SES raw email?

Tags: bash, amazon-ses

I have a variable tmpDir that contains multiple attachments.

I'd like to just add the directory to the email, but all the examples I've found so far are for sending file-attachments.

How do you attach a folder?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to add a directory to the email. You could create the zip archive from the directory and add this as a file to the email. The other way is to just walk through all the files in the directory and add it as a separate file. I think in your case the first option is better, but just keep in mind the limitations of the sending emails on SES (by default for sending is 10 MB, but can be increased to even 40 MB).